# Extra computation steps on adding brackets?

Tags: arithmetic-expressions, processing-efficiency

Ok, so just a question popped up in my mind while writing some code.
Does the CPU compute this

```
gap = (gap*3) + 1;
```

with the same efficiency as the below expression without the brackets?

```
gap = gap*3 + 1;
```

Update to be more clarifying:

Often while writing arithmetic expressions, we tend to add brackets to make the code easier to read, even if the brackets do not change what the expression evaluates to. So the question is, does adding such brackets have any affect on the performance?

Comment: Have a look at operator precedence/ order of operation - in your example the multiplication would anyway go first. The CPU does not directly execute expressions as you have posted them but executed instructions. It depends on what the compiler translates the source code to. The brackets would anyway me "removed". For your example there shouldn't be any difference (try and compile). Depending on your architecture this might even be done in a single instruction (multiply, add).

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question to explain it better.

Comment: In your example the results of both computations is the same. The calculations performed (instructions executed) to get those results is the same, so same performance. The data dependency has not changed.

Comment: Okay, I may surprisingly not be right (testing it on your example)! Other comments are welcome.

Comment: I wrote your program as C code and compared the assembly code and the binary program. It only differs by the file name, if you want I can add the code as an answer. But I am not sure if that is very helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks. You can post this as answer. I should have thought of trying this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above in the comments:

file test1.c:

```
int main(void)
{
    int gap = 1;
    gap = (gap*3) + 1;
    return gap;
}
```

file test2.c:

```
int main(void)
{
    int gap = 1;
    gap = gap*3 + 1;
    return gap;
}
```

Using `gcc` and its `-S` option ("Compile only; do not assemble or link"): `gcc -S test1.c && gcc -S test2.c`. Comparing those two files:

```
$ diff test1.s test2.s
1c1
<   .file   "test1.c"
---
>   .file   "test2.c"
```

(i.e. only the file names differ in the first line)

When you still don't believe me (for this particular example), then you can further compile & assemble: `gcc test1.c -o test1 && gcc test2.c -o test2`. Comparing those binary files (or rather ELF executables) will give you one byte difference, i.e. the file name again:

```
$ hexdump -C test1 > hex1.txt && hexdump -C test2 > hex2.txt
$ diff hex1.txt hex2.txt 
387c387
< 00001fc0  79 5f 65 6e 74 72 79 00  74 65 73 74 31 2e 63 00  |y_entry.test1.c.|
---
> 00001fc0  79 5f 65 6e 74 72 79 00  74 65 73 74 32 2e 63 00  |y_entry.test2.c.|
```